# What is difference between CFrameWndEx::AdjustDockingLayout() and CFrameWndEx::RecalcLayout()?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

What is difference between `CFrameWndEx::AdjustDockingLayout()` and `CFrameWndEx::RecalcLayout()` ?

Both of them to do similar tasks as documentation says: [AdjustDockingLayout()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb982189%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), [RecalcLayout()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc665495.aspx).

Besides that, [Interface Elements doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309030.aspx) says that

> You can call **AdjustDockingLayout** or **RecalcLayout** when you have **to adjust the docking layout, and the framework redirects this call to the docking manager**.

Does the `AdjustDockingLayout()` and `RecalcLayout()` perform same work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AdjustDockingLayout` is one level below `RecalcLayout`. The `RecalcLayout` calls `AdjustDockingLayout`. But `AdjustDocinkgLayout` has an additional parameter for defered windows positioning (HDWP).

So when the layout of windows are restored from the registry when you start the program or have a mode switch, `RecalcLayout` isn't called. In this case `AdjustDockingLayout` is called.

So whenever you need it internally I would always call `RecalcLayout`.

In detail: `RecalcLayout` calls `RecalcLayout` for each of its child windows too and finally calls `AdjustDockingLayout` for the current window only.

Comment: Thank you, but what work performed by RecalcLayout before call AdjustDockingLayout internally ? Is it safe to calling AdjustDockingLayout() instead RecalcLayout() if I know that window is placed normally and no resizing ?

Comment: In detail; RecalcLayout does some calculation and calls RecalcLayout for all of its children. AdjustLayout only affects the current window. ´So it just resizes the internal elements of the current window. Again: I always would call RecalcLayout

Comment: Small addition. For CDockablePane, CPane and CBasePane virtual method RecalcLayout() is not called never! Only AdjustLayout() called by framework. So, if your pane contains child window and toolbars then you need to overwrite AdjustLayout() method.